# Youtube loadPlaylist is not always working

Tags: javascript, youtube

`this.player` is `window['YT'].player`
`theVideo.videoListId` is the id pulled from Youtube link list?=....

The code below isn't ALWAYS working (it doesn't load some of videos). The Youtube url link is working if I paste the link to URL.

is the `loadPlaylist` method obsolete?

Can anyone tell me why?

```
this.player.loadPlaylist(
    {
      list: theVideo.videoListId,
      listType: 'playlist',
      index:0
   }
);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope someone answers this question.  What I have learn is that I have to take the videolistId and query it to the googleapis website to get all of the video Id associated with it.  To query it, I need to get API_KEY from google.
I am new to this and that is the reason why I run into this situation.
I hope this will explain well to the next person who got stuck with it.

It works after that.

Thank you.